# how to use php to produce a query according to an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$sql_t=Array ( [Processor] => Array ( [0] => i3 ) [Memory] => Array ( [0] => 8GB [1] => 32GB ) )


$sql_s="SELECT * FROM table "
  if(empty($sql_t))
    $sql=$sql_s;
  else{
    $sql=$sql_s.'where ';
    $first=true;
    foreach($sql_t as $a =>$b){
      foreach ($b as $x => $y){
        if(count($b)==1){
        $sql .=(($first) ? "":" AND ")."$a='$y'";
        $first=false;}
        else{
            $sql .=(($first) ? "":" OR ")."$a='$y'";    
        $first=false;}
    }   
    }
    }

 echo "<br/>query terms: ".$sql;
```

The result cannot show query with "and" and "or".

for example:query terms: SELECT * FROM table where Processor='i3' OR Memory='8GB' OR Memory='32GB'.

the right ansower should be "query terms: SELECT * FROM table where Processor='i3' AND Memory='8GB' OR Memory='32GB' .

Comment: I doubt that that's the 'right' answer!!

Comment: you have to use () sign in query to give which condition is combine and which is not

Answer (score 0):

I could not repair your code. This is my approach

```
$sql_s="SELECT * FROM table where ";
$sql_t= Array ( 
      'Processor' => Array ( 'i3' ), 
      'Memory' => Array ('8GB','32GB' ) 
);

foreach($sql_t as $a =>&$b) {
  if( count($b) > 1) {
      $b =  "`$a` in (\"". implode('", "', $b) .'")';
  }
  else {
      $b = "`$a` = \"" . $b[0] . '"';
  }
}

$sql = $sql_s . implode (' AND ', $sql_t); 

// SELECT * FROM table where `Processor` = "i3" AND `Memory` in ("8GB", "32GB")
```